# Typesetting public transport timetables

Tags: packages

I know that Deutsche Bahn (German railway) is using (La)TeX to typeset their timetables. Are there any (freely available) packages that help in typesetting timetables? I'd be mostly interested in connection timetables, i.e. something like:

- take train 123 at 5:45 from SomeStation platform 1 in direction of SomeFarAwayStation
- [105 min]
- arrive at ChangeStation platform 3 at 7:30
- walk for 150 m to the bus stop SomeBusStop [3 min]
- take bus 987 at 7:38 in direction of SomeFarAwayBusStop
- ....

All of this of course should be prettily formatted, perhaps even with some icons (for "bus/train/...").

One layout that I like is the one of VGN: [timetable](https://www.vgn.de/ib/site/tools/TripPrint.php/VGN-Einzelverbindung.pdf?Id=1523260399_0.30841100&Idx=3)

[image]

Comment: I've done a translator from IVU to individual stop timetables some years ago.... all in LuaLaTeX with loads of Lua to parse and output TeX. Some EMBEDDED examples of what you want to achieve are welcome.

Comment: @Astrinus: I added an example of what it should look like, more or less.

Comment: Is the data in a specific form? Here Lua seems to fit a lot

Comment: @Astrinus: No, the data is in no specific form. Perhaps I should have made this clear. I am not pulling this out of any large database or have any other data.  Basically I just want to occasionally send somebody transport/access details and would type those things manually. So in principle I could just manually create a table, etc, but would prefer not having to think about the layout.

Comment: Do you need it to automatically convert leg durations into arrival times, or will you do that manually, with the emphasis of your question being solely the format.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, I'd provide all the data myself, manually. My only concern would be layout.

Comment: I'm quite surprised that DB, or any public agency in any nation, is using TeX for timetables. At least here in the USA, such timetables must also have accessible (digital) versions, yet creating accessible PDF via TeX is a pain. Much easier to do it in programs designed for the purpose.

Comment: I have continued to improve my posted answer, in case you were interested.

Comment: @RobtAll: What do you mean by "accessible PDF" and what programs do you prefer for that? Once the scripts have been set up I don't see why it would matter what program is used. It is not like DB is changing their timetable layout all the time.

Comment: "Accessible" refers to enhancements for the those who are visually impaired. Often they have special software apps to read accessible documents. For example, an accessible document might turn off all decorations, other than the most essential icons, so that there is more screen room for text. The text might be monospaced, using only black and white. There would be additional navigation features, not just hyperlinks. And finally, audio software would be able to read and interpret the data. In the USA, some government documents MUST be prepared that way. InDesign can do it, I believe.

Comment: More info: Actually, the original document creator might not apply all the accessibility features. That is a specialized job, which can be done later. But the original document must have the correct PDF "tags" so that the document structure can be interpreted. And, spaces between words must be real spaces (hex 20). The TeX `accsup` package does some of that, but support is incomplete. TeX was, and is, primarily intended for paper-printed math publications; anything else is incidental.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's a stab.  I've edited to create the environment `timetable`, which sets up the TABstack, and lets you fill in the details.  I've added a variety of helper macros for regular things, like

1. `\firststation`, `\nextstation`, and `\laststation` for the symbols in the first column;
2. `\terminus{}` and `\waypoint{}` for the names of the endpoint and waypoint stations;
3. `\routedetails[<direction modifier>]{<mode>}{<number>}{<direction>}` for the route data;
4. `\onbus`, `\onmetro`, and `\ontrain` to provide icons for the various transportation modes; and
5. `\depart{}`, `\arrive{}`, and `\duration{}` for the timing.

EDITED to use appropriate clipart

https://www.iconsdb.com/red-icons/bus-icon.html

http://www.clker.com/clipart-subway-blue.html

http://www.softicons.com/web-icons/awt-travel-blue-icons-by-awt-media/train-icon

(Make sure you use the latest version of `tabstackengine 2018/03/05 (V2.10)`)

The following MWE compiles as is, but if you download the cited icons, you can also uncomment the redefinitions to get those icons, as I show in the actual image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,amssymb,environ}
\newcommand\onbus{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{example-image-a}}% BUS
\newcommand\onmetro{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{example-image-b}}% METRO
\newcommand\ontrain{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{example-image-c}}% TRAIN
% UNCOMMENT THE REDEFINITIONS BELOW IF YOU DOWNLOADED THE ICONS
%% https://www.iconsdb.com/red-icons/bus-icon.html
%\renewcommand\onbus{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{bus-xxl}}
%% http://www.clker.com/clipart-subway-blue.html
%\renewcommand\onmetro{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{subway-blue-md}}
%% http://www.softicons.com/web-icons/awt-travel-blue-icons-by-awt-media/train-icon
%\renewcommand\ontrain{\includegraphics[width=2ex,height=2ex]{AWT-Train}}
%%%%
% THE pt DISTANCES ON NEXT LINE MAY NEED TO VARY WITH FONT AND FONTSIZE
\newcommand\Stellemark[2]{\smash{\stackon[5.5pt]{\stackunder[-.5pt]{$\square$}{%
  \textcolor{blue!70!black}{\rule[-#2]{2\fboxrule}{#2}}}}{%
  \textcolor{blue!70!black}{\rule{2\fboxrule}{#1}}}}\kern-5pt}
\newcommand\terminus[1]{\smash{\textcolor{green!50!black}{\textbf{#1}}}}
% THE \raisebox VALUE ON THE NEXT TWO LINES MAY NEED TO VARY WITH FONT AND FONTSIZE
\newcommand\waypoint[1]{\smash{\raisebox{-4pt}{\terminus{#1}}}\rlap{\hspace{1em}\TABrule}}
\newcommand\nextstation{\smash{\raisebox{-4.4pt}{\Stellemark{14pt}{14pt}}}}
\newcommand\firststation{\Stellemark{0pt}{14pt}}
\newcommand\laststation{\Stellemark{14pt}{0pt}}
\newcommand\duration[1]{\stackunder{}{#1 min.}}
\newcommand\routedetails[4][Richtung:\ ]{#2\ \stackunder{\textbf{#3}}{#1#4}}
\newcommand\depart[1]{ab #1}
\newcommand\arrive[1]{an #1}
\let\svTABrule\TABrule
\NewEnviron{timetable}[1]{%
  \noindent%
  \footnotesize%
  \sffamily%
  \setstackgap{S}{1pt}%
  \renewcommand\stacktype{L}%
  \setstacktabulargap{1em}%
  \def\TABruleshift{-2pt}%
  \fboxrule=1pt\relax%
  \renewcommand\TABrule{\textcolor{green!50!black}{\svTABrule}}%
  \def\tmp{\tabularShortstack{#1}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\BODY}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{timetable}{cclcclr}
 && \textbf{Haltestelle} & \textbf{Uhrzeit} & \textbf{Gleis} & 
 \textbf{Verkehrsmittel} & \textbf{Dauer}\\
%
 \TABcline{1-7}
%
 \firststation && \terminus{N\"urnberg Flughafen}& \depart{10:22}&& 
 \routedetails{\onmetro}{U2}{R\"othenbach}& \duration{7}\\
%
 &&&\arrive{10:29}&&&\\
%
 \nextstation&\TABrule&\waypoint{N\"urnberg Mooshof}&
 \TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\\ 
%
 &&&\depart{10:35} &7& \routedetails{\ontrain}{65}{R\"othenbach} & \duration{6}\\
%
 &&&\arrive{10:41}&12&&\\
%
 \nextstation&\TABrule&\waypoint{N\"urnberg Schoppershof}&
 \TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule&\TABrule\\ 
%
 &&&\depart{10:45}&&\routedetails[Nur: ]{\onbus}{73}{Dutzendteich}&\duration{11}\\
%
 \laststation && \terminus{N\"urnberg-Dutzendteich} & \arrive{10:56}&&&\\
%
 \TABcline{1-7}
\end{timetable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Very very good. You are excellent. My compliments.

Comment: It is amazing that you do this "just because". I am highly impressed. How much time did that take you?

Comment: @jlinkels The initial stab was pushing an hour, but I improved it throughout the day with other bells/whistles.  I did it for several reasons: 1) as the developer of `tabstackengine`, I thought it would help show off some of its capability relative to `tabular`; 2) as the developer/maintainer of my multi-1000 person org's technical report `\documentclass`, it is good for me to constantly hone my skills; 3) I thought a successful answer was ripe for harvesting a bit of reputation upvotes; and 4) some challenges are irresistible.

Comment: I can understand your points 1, 2, 3 and 4.  :)  I just wished I was so skilled.