# Railway timetables with TeX/LaTeX

Tags: tables

I have seen this question: [Typesetting public transport timetables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425561/typesetting-public-transport-timetables).
That deals with timetables for a particular journey. I am more concerned with route timetables showing all the services on a particular line, such as those of [Deutsche Bahn](http://kursbuch.bahn.de/hafas/kbview.exe/dn?rt=1&dosearch=1&searchmode=tableplus&table_nr=%20&controlpattern=P.ddd&mainframe=utable&tocinfo=reg_tab) or [the European Rail Timetable](https://timetableworld.com/ttw-viewer.php?token=3f675dfa-14e8-4409-acec-ed3b7e4cd3b7)

Here is a picture:

[image: picture of timetable]

My question is twofold:

1. Is there a "readymade" solution to making something like this? I have read that the Deutsche Bahn uses TeX/LaTeX to typeset its timetables, but whatever they use is probably not available to the public.
2. If not, how can one go about making a "template" for something like this? The list of stations and train timings would preferably be sourced from e. g. a CSV-file for each table.

The example picture is perhaps a bit more complex than is necessary here since it reuses a column for two trains. I don't really need this.

Comment: Ad 2.) there are packages like https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple and https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool which can help you getting there, still, probably, a lot left to do *manually*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please add an example of your .csv?

Comment: @CarLaTex I don't have such a CSV yet, it was just a suggestion. It could perhaps contain essentially the same data as is in the table (first row with the train numbers/details, and subsequent rows with the timings at each station for all the trains, one train per column). Basically, I could do the formatting for this in LibreOffice Calc or similar, to make it look like the examples, but I thought maybe LaTeX offers a better option.